# How to serve Django static files during development without having to run "collectstatic"?

Tags: django

I have a Django version 2.2.6 application that has my Django static files being served up from a separate dedicated file server.  I use the Django "collectstatic" command to update the static files on my file server whenever one of them changes.  I also use the django-pipeline package so that each static file contains a special string in the file name.  This prevents my users' browsers from loading a static file from cache if I've updated that file.  This configuration works perfectly.

I'm now in a phase in which I'm making constant changes to my CSS file to create a new look and feel to my website and it's a pain to have to remember to run the collectstatic command after each little change I make.  Is there a way I can temporarily "toggle" this collectstatic configuration off while I'm doing development so that I don't have to constantly run the collectstatic command?  I seem to recall there was a way to change the main urls.py file and set DEBUG = True to do something like this back in Django 1.8 but I don't see it mentioned in the latest Django documentation.  What is the current "best practice" for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it still is in the docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

In **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Or did I somehow missunderstand your question?

Comment: I don't think you misunderstood my question but the technique you've shown (which comes from the documentation) will not work.  The document say it only works if STATIC_URL is local, not a URL.  Since my static files reside on another server, the value is a URL, it's not local.

Comment: Unless there's a way to configure the Django settings (and possibly the urls.py file) to enable what I'm trying to do, the easiest workaround is simply to put the CSS file in question in the appropriate static files directory on the file server.